# How to update SelectionSet in `info` graphql?

Tags: python, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

## Context

I work with graphql in python ([graphql-core-3](https://graphql-core-3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)), and I have a GraphQL query that looks like this.

```
query One {
  library(id: "library_1") {
    name
    book {
      title
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}
```

When I investigate `info` object `info.field_nodes[0].selection_set.selections` I got selection set of `FieldNodes` that looks like that:

```
<class 'graphql.language.ast.SelectionSetNode'>
<class 'graphql.pyutils.frozen_list.FrozenList'> [FieldNode at 45:49, FieldNode at 54:95, FieldNode at 100:110]


# FieldNode at 45:49
name

# FieldNode at 54:95
book {
  title
  __typename
}

# FieldNode at 100:110
__typename
```

## Problem

In my second query set I added `results` field to wrap my data.

```
query All {
  allLibrary {
    results {
      name
      book {
        title
        __typename
      }
      __typename
    }
    __typename
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this causes a problem because query set is resolved from level of `allLibrary` not `library` as in the first example. The consequences of this structure is that `info.field_nodes[0].selection_set.selections` resolves fields incorrectly. Skiping, all the fields that I have interest in (`name` , `book`, `__typename`).

```py
<class 'graphql.language.ast.SelectionSetNode'>
<class 'graphql.pyutils.frozen_list.FrozenList'> [FieldNode at 14:147, FieldNode at 133:143] 

# FieldNode at 31:128
results {
  name
  book {
    title
    __typename
  }
  __typename
}

# FieldNode at 133:143
__typename
```

## Question

How I can fix my `info.field_nodes[0].selection_set` so it fetches the `FieldNode` correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was given [here](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphql-core/issues/135#issuecomment-877400186). I just needed to dig deeper in my selection_set.

```
info.field_nodes[0].selection_set.selections[0].selection_set.selections
```